# Bootstrap carousel show single item on mobile devices

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using bootsrtap carousel to create a carousel to show items horizontaly scrollable.

This is how it looks on desktop

[image]

and this is how it shows in mobile devices

[image]

This is the html code

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-type="multi" data-interval="2000" id="featuredCarousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="item active">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <!-- div content -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <!-- div content -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <!-- div content -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="item">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <!-- div content -->
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a class="left carousel-control text-info" href="#featuredCarousel" data-slide="prev"><i class="text-info glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control text-info" href="#featuredCarousel" data-slide="next"><i class="text-info glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></a>
</div>
```

and this is the javascript code

```
<script>
$(function() {

    $('#featuredCarousel').carousel({
        interval: 10000
    })
    console.log($('.item'))
    $('.item').each(function() {

        var next = $(this).next();
        console.log(next);
        if (!next.length) {
            next = $(this).siblings(':first');
        }
        next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

        if (next.next().length > 0) {
            next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        } else {
            $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

**Number of divisions are good in desktop view, but I want to show only one item on mobile and rest on slide.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use [Flickity](http://flickity.metafizzy.co/) instead. If you organize your carousel items into Bootstrap columns (for example put each item into a "col-md-4") then Flickity will respect the Bootstrap CSS and recognize the number of items to scroll per screen resolution.